# Steam games to a flash drive

Tags: games, flash, steam, drive

I have more problems than you can shake a stick at. I want to be able to play my steam games on a flash drive because i am using a chromebook (x86) and it does not have enough storage. my problem is when i go to add a new download folder and pick the flash drive it says "new steam folder must be empty". so i was going to try to movie steam to the flash drive using "mv ~/.local/share/Steam /new/path" but it says no such file directory. someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new (empty) directory on your flash drive (e. g. with Nautilus or any other file manager) and
2. use the Steam settings dialogue to configure it as alternative library location.